# All outbound emails from my domain get marked as spam

Tags: email, spam

I have a domain, www.duckfox.com, that was using Google Apps mail servers, and now is using Zoho.  All outbound emails that I send out will always go to spam, unless that person has already marked that message as not spam.  They don't even reach yahoo.com email accounts because it'll bounce with the error code 554: Message not allowed (Email not accepted for policy reasons).  One of the reasons is supposedly "Malformed Headers", but I don't know how they could be malformed.

I have checked a number of sites that will inform you if your domain is blacklisted, and they all report that we are clean.  Also, with Google Apps, I did have DKIM and SPF records and signatures in place (I do not yet have these in place with Zoho because I just set up the account).  I'm at a loss for what I may need to change or do so that our outbound messages aren't flagged as spam any longer.  It's getting to urgent status for us as we can't communicate with anyone.

Here is an example of a rejected email from when I was still going through Google Apps (which I'd love to still use if this can get fixed):

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:



    stharlow992000@yahoo.com

    Technical details of permanent failure:
    Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain yahoo.com bymta7.am0.yahoodns.net. [63.250.192.46].

    The error that the other server returned was:
    554 Message not allowed - [PH01] Email not accepted for policy reasons.  Please visit https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN5067.html [120]


    ----- Original message -----

    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
            d=duckfox.com; s=google;
            h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to;
            bh=7hQTxe59PmWrLv1TiDZppInmn46Tx/e088kNarw6WFo=;
            b=e0Hqe9wQ+4A644kWxiOcCq70jPbws3NuggldNnhFcD3Ogwjf0Fyzv1xuSwqOh+BeGp
             h0zNOyj1ws+bGkaaYrcjNBNAkXYxRhy9kbc2rqoUtSlEI0l/RSe4WG/y/5MpDw5Y8LNd
             tXaQxGxOaEVB0/d0KlnH/tZzi16iynMOnjC+U=
    X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
            d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
            h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to;
            bh=7hQTxe59PmWrLv1TiDZppInmn46Tx/e088kNarw6WFo=;
            b=JWYWXId/R6684XEnpXYj7kGR1jg3WIgPma/BdrUjvogljXLDRu1B9OX/LbupOSdEu3
             jSYXF2LB0umD9PfVzLF0uYjADlJOg+y5fRvcXxAOU2cvu/vlRDaj+L/wBZA+2iHkIqr6
             mSXaPfeOc9hA0D+RjfvqykXlRH5Q/5q606OYxpjomzieK9cXVypnBYe5PZ13jCBHJafU
             ItsZA1nxVRyKEFDFhDdgUnnQDlA8s5BLUybLSgYYFwCXavXMSlZrLqZ4D6Nx4lBnsxQU
             MtYcvIrk/Pe1lLO0qoCmrwpTbFkw8jGVkzW52xjOOB9gvHnM2v+G9OyVIVNGKq7M09CN
             eq4Q==
    X-Gm-Message-State: ALyK8tJfX4k/Qe67VFmmArLnb/VDQLC1+CY2F8eXZFUS2xJkbgrn08bMJsGRtiH3wbs2ePijYOtIY12p0UcLqw==
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    X-Received: by 10.28.22.77 with SMTP id 74mr7202427wmw.36.1466113866305; Thu,
     16 Jun 2016 14:51:06 -0700 (PDT)
    Received: by 10.194.13.193 with HTTP; Thu, 16 Jun 2016 14:51:06 -0700 (PDT)
    X-Originating-IP: [73.71.224.187]
    Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2016 14:51:06 -0700
    Message-ID: <CAEakwwSPK_9KUm2Xcuj-TsNgJQ+swi6-eav-CrDFZFjzB+stnw@mail.gmail.com>
    Subject: test
    From: Steven Harlow <steve@duckfox.com>
    To: stharlow992000@yahoo.com
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11467c5033c2ec05356c3cc9

    testing
```

DNS Records (CNAME, MX, TXT, NS  in that order):

```
ftp @   1 Hour  
s1._domainkey   s1.domainkey.u3132155.wl156.sendgrid.net    1 Hour  
s2._domainkey   s2.domainkey.u3132155.wl156.sendgrid.net    1 Hour  
support u3132155.wl156.sendgrid.net 1 Hour  
www hokkaido-96747.herokussl.com    1 Hour

5   @   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 1 Hour  
5   @   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 1 Hour  
10  @   ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 1 Hour  
10  @   ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 1 Hour  
1   @   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM  1 Hour


@   google-site-verification=aCtaJMgHSSLEb2NGlMoAutcluizi49yCkX6BORdnLpo    1 Hour  
    @   v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.net ~all    1 Hour  
    google._domainkey   v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCdhOeuNciUlITqCv2pK3H8yuibzd3StcMjXXD3zSd1IcaeBX1awEF6KbQ0k+NzPkSGMGwHCoGvnJ9bu9LQ74BbbMOfL/fay/KGcqi8wW8EqEy9GbT1XP97PhMLIaWloc85BfUjJy9Sb00Mdi21d6JMYd4+9xgqZF+HnBPdPBWxJwIDAQAB  1 Hour

@ (Informational)   ns19.domaincontrol.com (Informational)  1 Hour (Informational)  
@ (Informational)   ns20.domaincontrol.com (Informational)  1 Hour (Informational)
```

Comment: @EEAA I don't really think that the referenced question and it's answers is a duplicate.  1) I am going through Google Apps, so a lot of the suggestions are taken care of through their service (clean server, "Steven Harlow" in from section, etc), 2) I don't create spammy messages.  These are messages like "Test" or just normal messages to my personal emails.  We have never bulk emailed anyone and our volume of emails has been below 100 total. 3) I've checked, and the domain is not blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you created a DKIM and SPF record on Google Apps. After you moved to Zoho, you **need** to do the same thing.

Here is a link to [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/campaigns/help/setup-spf-dkim.html) that will show you how and what SPF and DKIM records to add to your DNS.

From my understanding, without an SPF and DKIM record, your emails are not verified. This means Yahoo! cannot verify that you are sending the email.

EDIT: Could you please post your all of your DNS records?

Comment: This bounce was happening from Google Apps.  I've already created SPF and DKIM records for Zoho, and I'm just waiting for them to propagate, but I'm actually rather concerned that the issue is going to persist.  This not only happened from Google Apps, but also when email was sent through SendGrid, which was white-labeled.

Comment: Could you post all of your DNS records? I just did a lookup on your domain and I do see missing values.

Comment: Beside those that are showing currently when performing dig -t ANY duckfox.com, I have the DKIM record which hasn't propagated yet:

v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCdhOeuNciUlITqCv2pK3H8yuibzd3StcMjXXD3zSd1IcaeBX1awEF6KbQ0k+NzPkSGMGwHCoGvnJ9bu9LQ74BbbMOfL/fay/KGcqi8wW8EqEy9GbT1XP97PhMLIaWloc85BfUjJy9Sb00Mdi21d6JMYd4+9xgqZF+HnBPdPBWxJwIDAQAB

Comment: Though, the thing I'm worried about is that even when we were looking at my DNS records after they'd all propagated earlier in the week, they all looked good and were showing, but the mail was still being sent to spam.

Comment: Please append `include:zoho.com` into your SPF record, wait a good amount of time for propagation, and then send an email. After you send the email, please check on the headers to see if the SPF verification says `pass` or `failed`

Comment: Also, can you confirm with me whether you are **currently** using Google Apps for emailing OR Zoho mail? From your post, you said you moved to Zoho for email. If that is the case, you need to also include [MX records](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/configure-email-delivery.html) from Zoho

Comment: Yeah sorry, at the time I had switched to Zoho, but I've switched back to Google Apps.  Both the SPF record and the MX records should be current for google (include:google and the mx pointing the right location)

Comment: Steven, can you email my random email, `laffytaffykidd@gmail.com`. I will review the headers when you send me a random email. EDIT: Once you send me an email, head over to your [email log search](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2618874) and see if it gives you an error.

Comment: I sent it and it says it went through.  I'd check your spam inbox :/


Subject: 
Thanks for helping with this
Sender: 
steve@duckfox.com
Recipient: 

One recipient
Date: 
Jun 18, 2016, 12:00
Message ID: 
<CAEakwwQ=yOVc5WmYtEs-AoHuOLBbjcPAqXgk6c6xYJ77o6-M2w@mail.gmail.com>
Message size: 
1.17KB
Attachments: 
0
Direction: 
Sent
Status: 
1/1 Delivered

Comment: From the looks of the email headers, everything in the DNS looks good. It seems like Google Apps setting. Are you using a Google SMTP relay? If so, on the Google Apps admin panel, `Apps` > `Google Apps` > `Gmail` > `Advanced Settings` > Search for `SMTP relay service` > Click `Edit` and add your server's IP address.